Can I put schottky diodes in I2C line to prevent LTC2944 from powering my circuit through SDA and SCL?
I am using a LTC2944 connected to a battery that fluctuates between 11V and 14.4V. SDA and SCL lines go to a microcontroller and other peripherals (also connected to 3V3 via 10k resistors). I can read the address 1100100 via I2C and the other peripherals so the connections should be good.
The thing is that SDA and SCL where both at 1.1 volts and 3V3 was at 700mV although my 3V3 power supply was off. I tried shorting a 5k resistor from SDA to ground and SDA decreased to 400mV not 0V as I would have hoped for. Then I cut SDA and SCL traces of the LTC2944 to the rest of the circuit and SDA and SCL on the powered off side decreased to 40mV, much better. (on the other hand SDA and SCL on the LTC2944 raised to 4.1V and when I put my finger it increases to 5V, this is repeatable)
So it was effectively leaking current into the circuit section that was supposed to be powered off (mcu and peripherals). I suspect this is the cause the LSM303AGR IC on my circuit burnt out when it was supposed to be powered off.
Can I do the following to prevent this leakage ? Are there more efficient ways in terms of cost ? On the datasheet of the LTC2944 it says that SDA and SCL lines must always be HIGH when I2C is IDLE so thats why the Zeners:

EDIT:
I have got 4k7 resistors on SDA and SCL. "CHARGE" is connected to the battery through 25 mili ohm resistor.


That's never going to work, and you're thinking about fixing your problem in the wrong way.
I2C lines need these passive pull-up resistors because the ICs on each end can only drive the signals low. Your diodes will prevent that from happening, and you'll have no I2C comms.
What you should do instead is connect the pullup resistors from SDA & SCL to your MCUs 3.3v supply instead of "CHARGE". Also use a sensible value like 4k7 at the most.

The I2C bus interface will not work as implemented. The pullup resistors should be 2k to 3.3V not to "charge". 680k is way to big. Don't expect  much current drive out of ALCC. A reference design is in the datasheet on page 17, complete with some protection. It shows the correct way to interface the I2C.


Can I put schottky diodes in I2C line to prevent LTC2944 from powering my circuit through SDA and SCL?

The battery should first be disconnected with a relay or a FET.

How can I charge the battery if it is disconnected

To continue to charge the battery with the monitor while the microcontroller is powered down, the I2C bus must be disconnected. However, the 3.3V to the bus pull-up resistors must be maintained.
The bus must be held in idle state.
A small buck converter can be used to generate the 3.3V from the “charge” node. Three terminal versions with built-in inductor are available.

How could I prevent the LTC2944 to leak into "uP" when 3V3 is OFF ? I have got 4k7 resistors on SDA and SCL, not shown in the schematic.

The battery should first be disconnected with a relay or a FET. @TomásArturoHerreraCastro

How can I charge the battery if it is disconnected ?
